# I want each iteration to update items when I push an object to an array of objects

Tags: ractivejs

I want to add 1000 objects to an array of objects and I iterate this array with each iterator

I want each item pushed to be followed by updated view in the browser

Answer (score 0):

while I was trying to make a simple example of my question I found the solution to my question:
my solution using setTimeout() and for loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i<=1000; i++){
setTimeout(() => { ractive.push('arrayName',{key:value,key2:value}), i * 100}
}
```

[jsfiddle live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ezngcdxj/1/)

the source for the setTimeout() idea: [Delay, Sleep, Pause & Wait in JavaScript - sitepoint.com](https://www.sitepoint.com/delay-sleep-pause-wait/)